# While Loop not working

Tags: java

please can someone help me ? I have wrote this code and that dont work. I dont know what is bad.

```
public class Whileloop {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String equation ="+1x+1x+2=+1x+1x+6";
    String parts[] = equation.split("=");
    int no = 0;
    System.out.println(parts[no]);
    int helper = 5;
    for (parts[0].charAt(helper) != '-' || parts[0].charAt(helper) != '+';helper--) {
        System.out.println(helper);

    }
    System.out.println(helper);

  }
}
```

This is the result:

```
+1x+1x+2
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: -1
>         at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
>         at Whileloop.main(Whileloop.java:12)

Comment: "that dont work" doesn't explain what you expect it to do or what it actually does. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `parts[0].charAt(helper) != '-' || parts[0].charAt(helper) != '+'` can never be false.

Comment: So where's the `while` loop? You've only got a `for` loop. And have you tried debugging through your code? Basically, it looks like `helper` is reaching -1, at which point `parts[0].charAt(helper)` is invalid. But we don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: `helper` will certainly get negative.

Comment: When do you want loop to stop?

Comment: I want to stop loop when  parts[0].charAt(helper) eqauls '+' or '-'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it is giving the expected output :

```
 +1x+1x+2
5
4
3
2
1
0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
        at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
        at Test.main(Test.java:10)
```

First it prints "**parts**" up to '=' sign that is **+1x+1x+2**. Then it enters the loop with helper value equal to 5. Then helper is decreased by one and it displays 4. Finally it goes to -1 and thus giving IndexOutOfBound Exception. 
 You should use && instead of ||.

Comment: for (;parts[0].charAt(helper) != '-' || parts[0].charAt(helper) != '+';helper--) {
            System.out.println(helper);
        }
and what about this ? it should stops when helper 0 or 3, because then 
parts[0].charAt(helper) == '+'.

Comment: here u are decreasing helper and using it as index also which after becoming -1 is giving error.

Comment: But thing with Logical OR (||) is that it does not test second condition if first is true.So parts[0].charAt(helper) != '-' evaluates to true. Thus true||false = true.

Comment: I want to stop loop when parts[0].charAt(helper) eqauls '+' or '-'.

Comment: Use && instead of ||

Comment: but why is it like this ? it works after that ty so much man but i though, that or (||) means if parts[0].charAt(helper) eqauls '+' stop or parts[0].charAt(helper) eqauls '-' . and about && i though its like if arts[0].charAt(helper) eqauls '-' and this as well parts[0].charAt(helper) eqauls '+' then stop

Answer (score 0):

helper will become "-1" and hence charAt(-1) is throwing exception because "-1" is an invalid place. you can check helper > 0 && (your condition) to make it work :)

Comment: I want to stop loop when parts[0].charAt(helper) eqauls '+' or '-'.  so what should i do ?

Comment: u can modify ur check "parts[0].charAt(helper) != '-' || parts[0].charAt(helper) != '+'" to something like this 

(helper >= 0) && (parts[0].charAt(helper) != '-' || parts[0].charAt(helper) != '+')

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Whileloop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String equation = "+1x+1x+2=+1x+1x+6";
        String parts[] = equation.split("=");
        int no = 0;
        System.out.println(parts[no]);
        int helper = 5;
        for (; parts[0].charAt(helper) != '-' || parts[0].charAt(helper) != '+'; helper--) {
            if(helper == 0){
                break;
            }else{
            System.out.println(helper);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(helper);
    }
}
```

Output:
+1x+1x+2
5
4
3
2
1
0